# Kafka connect error handling and improved logging

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I was trying to leverage some enhancements in Kafka connect in 2.0.0 release as specified by this KIP https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-298%3A+Error+Handling+in+Connect and I came across this good blog post by Robin https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues.

Here are my questions

1. I have set `errors.tolerance=all` in my connector config. If I understand correctly, it will not fail for bad records and move forward. Is my understanding correct?
   In my case, the consumer doesn't fail and stays in the `RUNNING` state (which is expected) but the consumer offsets don't move forward for the paritions with the bad records. Any guess why this may be happening?
2. I have set `errors.log.include.messages` and `errors.log.enable` to true for my connector but I don't see any additional logging for the failed records. The logs are similar to what I used to see before enabling these properties. I didn't see any message like this https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/5a95c2e1cd555d5f3ec148cc7c765d1bb7d716f9/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/errors/LogReporter.java#L67

Some Context:
In my connector, I do some transformations, validations for every record and if any of these fail, I throw `RetriableException`. Earlier I was throwing `RuntimeException` but I changed to [RetriableException](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/errors/RetriableException.html) after reading the comments for [RetryWithToleranceOperator](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/errors/RetryWithToleranceOperator.java) class.

I have tried to keep it brief but let me know if any additional context is required.

Thanks so much in advance!